# Understanding「この中で物事の『程度』を示す新しい表現について聞いたところ、「とても」を意味する『めっちゃ』については、定着したことを示す「ほかの人が使うのが気にならない」と答えた人が81％に上り、58％が「使うことがある」と答えました。」

Tags: grammar, parsing

I need help understanding this sentence from this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20210925/k10013275571000.html),

> この中で物事の『程度』を示す新しい表現について聞いたところ、「とても」を意味する『めっちゃ』については、定着したことを示す「ほかの人が使うのが気にならない」と答えた人が81％に上り、58％が「使うことがある」と答えました。

It's difficult for me to follow this sentence. Does「聞いたところ」mean the same thing as「聞いたところで」which means "at situation when we asked about..."?

Also, I don't understand the meaning of 定着 in「定着したことを示す」. Is「定着したことを示す」modifying「ほかの人が使うのが気にならない」?

How the whole sentence is parsed? Is that right

> (この中で物事の『程度』を示す新しい表現について聞いたところ)、((「とても」を意味する『めっちゃ』については、定着したことを示す)「ほかの人が使うのが気にならない」と答えた人が81％に上り)、(58％が「使うことがある」と答えました。)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the 「～たところで」 meaning "as soon as". This [「～たところ」](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/09/14/jlptn3-grammar-tatokoro/) means A happened, and then B unexpectedly happened. There is a stressed implication that B was not expected to happen; and there is a strong element of surprised associated with the occurrence or discovery of B.

Note that the two usages could both translate as "when", but the former stresses a temporal connection between the two events, whereas the latter conveys a sense of unexpectedness.

So here, 「Aについて聞いたところ、B」 means "when asked about A, (the event) B happened"

定着{ていちゃく} means for a habit to become established. 定着したことを示す means "to state that (the habit) has become established," and it indeed modifies 「ほかの人が使うのが気にならない」.

> この中で物事の『程度』を示す新しい表現について聞いたところ、「とても」を意味する『めっちゃ』については、定着したことを示す「ほかの人が使うのが気にならない」と答えた人が81％に上り、58％が「使うことがある」と答えました。

can be rendered as:

> In this survey/study, when asked about using new phrases to describe the degree of things, as many as 81% of the surveyed people answered they were used to using めっちゃ to mean 「とても」 by indicating they wouldn't notice it when other people use that phrase; and 51% said they sometimes use it themselves.

Comment: How would you fit 定着したことを示す in your translation?

Comment: @aguijonazo That part is already there in my translation, rendered as "answered they were used to". This is 意訳, as opposed to 直訳. And it is a rough rendering of the original line, which I provided because OP has stated they needed help with understanding the overall structure of the Japanese text. So it is not a word-for-word direct translation, and wasn't aimed to be one, because [we don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/30454) on this site. That's why I took the liberty of changing the structure and I believe my version remains faithful to the semantics.

Comment: With all due respect, it is the choice of ほかの人が使うのが気にならない that indicates that the phrase in question has been established. It is a static property of this choice. It’s not that 81% of the people (directly) stated that the phrase has been established. I thought this distinction was important when understanding the structure of this sentence.

Comment: @aguijonazo I really appreciate your helpful input, as always! What I was getting at is while I totally see your point and where you are coming from, it wasn't a knowledge gap, parse failure, or mistake on my part. It was a conscious choice that I made to give a quick and dirty rendering of a long and fairly difficult Japanese passage. I took some liberties with the translation, modifying the structure and moving what's conveyed in 定着したことを示す to a different location. Yes, I know 定着したことを示す is connected to ほかの人が使うのが気にならない in an NP, as stated in the answer, but I found it hard to render that way.

Comment: @aguijonazo As you can see from the edit history, I first gave a quick explanation of the grammar points. Then came the idea of rendering the whole passage in English to help clear up any doubts on the semantic front, which sorta happened only as an afterthought. At that time, I found it difficult to do a literal translation and connect it with the rest of the text, so I moved it so that it modified the survey subjects as opposed to the option they went for. I still don't think my modified version strayed far from the original semantically, even though I broke up the noun phrase.

Comment: I'm even under the impression this kind of translation technique occurs all the time. I'd be willing to go as far as look for actual examples from professional translators. Let's put a pin in this. And I will follow up here in the comments with real-world examples as I come across them.